# Customize xticks in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a figure which has the `xticks` starting from, for example, `50` to `100`.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
data_to_plot = data[-90:]  # 90 datapoints

# Create figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Plot the value
ax.plot(data_to_plot/S)

# Set the ticks
x_ticks = np.arange(50, 140)
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)

# Limits
plt.ylim(0, 1)

# Naming
plt.title("Cooperation")
plt.xlabel("Round")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

And what I get is this figure:

[image: Plot]

Instead of a figure with the *xticks* starting from `50` up to `140`, i.e., the list [50, 60, 70, ..., 130, 140] for the labels in the xticks.

**Using:**
Python 3, Matplotlib 3.0.2, MacOS 10.13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to specify the x-values as well when you are plotting the graph.
Then, based on the level of detail you need, set the x_ticks.

```
# Plot the value
x_ticks = np.arange(50, 140)
ax.plot(x_ticks,data_to_plot)

# Set the ticks
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(50, 140,10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a spacing of 10 while creating your ticks as

```
np.arange(50, 140, 10)
```

The default spacing in `np.arange` is 1 which means `np.arange(50, 140)` which result in an array `[50, 51, 52, ... 139]`